# Is there a specific way to use env var keys for Firebase apps running in Cloud Run?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, vite

I tried to put the firebase sdk api key into .env (currently, vite)

I have the two env modes set up likeso:

```js
.env
VITE_APP_API_KEY=SOME_KEY

.env.production
VITE_APP_API_KEY=SOME_KEY


firebase.js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_KEY,
...
};
```

This runs fine locally, and the env import (`import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_KEY`) returns the value. Once I deploy it to Cloud Run,
`Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).`
The `import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_KEY` returns undefined.

Curious why this is.